Decoding data from accountSubscribe Websocket method. RUST
I'm trying to find a correct schema for base64 decoded data, that i get from accountSubscribe WSS method. As a subscription address i use base and quote assets' vault addresses.
so the request looks like:
let request_json_rpc: serde_json::Value = serde_json::json!({
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "accountSubscribe",
        "params": [
          vault_address,
          {
            "encoding": "jsonParsed",
            "commitment": "confirmed"
          }
        ]
    });

and the response looks like:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "accountNotification",
  "params": {
    "result": {
      "context": {
        "slot": 298423747
      },
      "value": {
        "data": [
          "ykGKaepGFLQHCirRxFiYQFSme+FyzCJg4Yt5R8zsSARBV7BYDzHF/ORKYlgtvPnXjudZQ6CEo5OzUDaNIomTCGAvdCo8RQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
          "base64"
        ],
        "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
        "lamports": 2039280,
        "executable": false,
        "space": 165
      }
    },
    "subscription": 16127
  }
}



i successfully decode the data using base64 crate and specifically general_purpose::STANDARD.decode() method, however without schema i dont know how to deal with bytes then.
I would appreciate any help.

Its really hard to know what data is in that account and how its serialized without any more info.
If this is an anchor program and it has a IDL uploaded you can use that to decode the data like this:
You can either directly fetch and account like this
    let storageStruct = await program.account.storage.fetch(
      storage
    );

and since you are using websocket you can use the decoder from the anchor program like this:
let program = new Program(IDL as Lumberjack, provider);
...
connection.onAccountChange(pda, (account) => {
      const newGameData = program.coder.accounts.decode(
        "gameData",
        account.data
      );
      setGameData(newGameData);
      setTotalWoodAvailable(newGameData.totalWoodCollected.toNumber());
    });

where gameData is the name of the account in camelCase.
Here is a complete program and websocket decoding example:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-preset/blob/main/app/contexts/GameStateProvider.tsx
If you have source code access you should be able to find the IDL there, if the program uploaded the idl and you have the program id you can find it in the Solana explorer:
https://explorer.solana.com/
